# Highcharts Angular - Property 'data' does not exist on type 'SeriesAbandsOptions'

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, data-binding

I'm trying to set the data of my chart using a REST API but I get the following error:
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'SeriesAbandsOptions'

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chartService.getMostFrequentUpdateData().subscribe(
      (data: ChartData[]) => {
        if(this.chartOptions.series){
          this.chartOptions.series[0].data = data;
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

I get the error on `.data`.
For clarity, this is my chart:

```
chartOptions: Options = {

  title: {
      text: 'CDF of the most frequent update frequency',
      style: {
        color: 'whitesmoke'
      }
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'line',
      zoomType: 'x',
      backgroundColor: '#323232',
    },
...

  series: [
      {
        name: 'Frequency of the most frequent update in the sequence (upd/min)',
        type: 'line',
        data: [],
        color: '#009879',
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: What is `SeriesAbandsOptions` ?

Comment: @JosephBudin I've got no idea

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on stackblitz

Comment: @OwenKelvin Heres the link, unfortunately i'm getting some errors upon importing, they don't seem to make sense https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-j52fy4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fhome%2Fmodal-most-frequent-update%2Fmodal-most-frequent-update.component.ts

Comment: Could you share a public repo I try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @OwenKelvin Yes here it is, https://github.com/mauri5566/sitocopy

Comment: I have checked the repo and tried to run it. The errors are unfortunately not anywhere near the error you have shared. I am getting unmerged changes and after resolving those loads and loads of typescript errors.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some TS definitions are missing.
You have two options:

1. Cast everything to `any` - rather brutal.
2. Create additional interface the extends the existing `SeriesAbandsOptions` with the missing `data` type.

**Simple demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-property-xxx-doesnt-exist-on-type-yyy**